# How to covert labels array into one vector of letters

Tags: python, arrays

I have the labels as the following:
`array([[1., 0., 0., 0.], [1., 0., 0., 0.], [1., 0., 0., 0.], ..., [1., 0., 0., 0.], [0., 0., 1., 0.], [0., 0., 0., 1.]], dtype=float32)`

How can I turn this into one vector that has for example a letter representing each class
[a,
a,
a,
b,
c,
d]

Comment: You can traverse through the array and save those float values into a mapping to other characters. Is it only for `0.0` and `1.0`, or for a lot of them? What code do you have right now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `np.argmax()` with `map()`:

```py
list(map(lambda x: chr(ord('a') + x), np.argmax(arr, axis=1)))
```

This outputs:

```py
['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'c', 'd']
```